# What's causing my Android splash screen image to appear off-center?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I have a splash screen in my application, which I've made following these instructions: https://medium.com/android-news/launch-screen-in-android-the-right-way-aca7e8c31f52

I managed to make it pop up after launch, but the image appears to be decentered.

Here is my launch_screen.xml drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item>

        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/enot_transp_stretch"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tileMode="disabled"
            />

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

I don't see any way to put image in center, other than `android:gravity="center"`. Someone mentioned that changing `android:windowBackground` to `android:background` in themes.xml might help. However in my case that didn't do much.